# iOS: Image is not displaying properly in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cornerradius

I have a `UIImageView` in which a `UIImage` is showing which comes from JSON. The problem is that I want to set the `cornerRadius` for the `UIImageView`. I put the following code for it:

```
imgVw.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0;
imgVw.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
imgVw.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

It displays the `cornerRadius` and border for `UIImageView` but not in the proper way. The image is showing outside the corners like in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `masksToBounds` property of `layer` to `YES` like this

```
self.imgVw.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property of `UIImageView` to `YES`.

Like

set `imgVw.clipsToBounds=YES;`

Comment: No, it should be `imgVw.clipsToBounds = YES;`. This is Objective-C.

Comment: What down vote? No one has down voted your answer. And you need to fix the typos in the first line too.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry I don't know who has downvoted but previously it was there.